# Zurb Foundation: Prevent empty column collapsing to zero width

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Using Foundation, I sometimes have an empty column in a row, and that column gets collapsed entirely, engendering a mismatch between column data and column headers. Is there a way that I can prevent this collapse, making even empty columns get full width? (Is there a way besides inserting non-breaking spaces or other text into the otherwise empty columns?)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-1 columns">Bruce</div>
  <div class="small-1 columns"></div> <!-- this gets collapsed to 0 width! -->
  <div class="small-1 columns">Dickinson</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Apply the following css:

```
.column, .columns{
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: This somehow fixes the width issues, despite applying to height. Thanks!

Comment: It's because its actually the lack of height which makes the divs collapse when rendered. Only their width is specified in the CSS, the height is determined by the content. If there's no content, the height is 0, and Zurb doesn't protect against this. See this similar Q&A http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/22995-empty-column

Answer (score 1):

You could add some pseudo content to the containing element to trigger rendering.

Markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p class="middlename"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.middlename:before {
  content: "\00a0";
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tag the last column (you are using) with "end".

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns">3</div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns">3</div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns end">3 end</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what this is supposed to do? I don't see it making any difference in my page. My problem is that one of the columns that is not on the end is getting collapsed.

Comment: I see you have re-edited your question. When you originally asked it you hadn't mentioned that the column could be anywhere in the grid. I assumed it would be the last column. Hence the above. Didn't think my answer was worth down voting though!

Comment: If it were the last column in the grid and it collapsed, that would not create the problem I described (before the edit): 'engendering a mismatch between column data and column headers'. I don't mean the downvote as personal criticism; I just think it's not a constructive response that's relevant to the problem I describe.